# Как считать время проведенное в голосовом канале?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код, который реагирует на вход в голосовой, и выход из него. При входе пишется "кто и куда присоединился", при выходе "кто откуда вышел". Как мне его изменить, чтобы он еще и считал время проведенное в голосовом канале?

```
global.bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
            const date = new Date();
            const member = newState.member;
            const currenttime = `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;
            const oldchan = oldState.channel;
            const newchan = newState.channel;
            if (newchan != oldchan) {
                if (oldchan) {
                    if (newchan) {
                        console.log(`${currenttime} - ${member.nickname || member.user.username} сменил канал с ${oldchan.name} на ${newchan.name}`);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log(`${currenttime} - ${member.nickname || member.user.username} ушёл ${oldchan.name}`);
                    }
                }
                else if (newchan) {
                    console.log(`${currenttime} - ${member.nickname || member.user.username} присоединился ${newchan.name}`);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: При входе писать время, когда вошёл. И отнимать от текущего времени время, когда вошёл.

Answer (score 0):

````
global.bot.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
            const date = new Date();
            const member = newState.member;
            const currenttime = `${date.getHours()}:${date.getMinutes()}:${date.getSeconds()}`;
            const oldchan = oldState.channel;
            const newchan = newState.channel;
            if (newchan != oldchan) {
                if (oldchan) {   
                    if (newchan) {
                        console.log(`${currenttime} - ${member.nickname || member.user.username} сменил канал с ${oldchan.name} на ${newchan.name}`);
                    }
                    else {
                        let leaveTime = Date.parse(new Date); //фиксация времени в мс при выходе из канала
                        let currentTime = (leaveTime-joinTime) / 1000; // проведенное время в секундах
                        console.log(`Прошло ${currentTime} секунд`);
                        console.log(`${currenttime} - ${member.nickname || member.user.username} ушёл ${oldchan.name}`);
                    }
                }
                else if (newchan) {
                    global.joinTime = Date.parse(new Date); // фиксация времени в мс при входе в канал
                    console.log(`${currenttime} - ${member.nickname || member.user.username} присоединился ${newchan.name}`);
                }
            }
        });
    ```
````